# What is the problem with my function "max8"?

Tags: lua

I have an error when i try to execute my code. "lua: main.lua:10: attempt to call a number value (global 'max2')stack traceback:main.lua:10: in function 'max4'main.lua:24: in function 'max8'main.lua:34: in main chunk[C]: in ?"

You will find my code below :

```
function max2(a, b) --fonction (max2)
    if a > b then -- si a est superieur à b alors...
      return a -- return a
    else -- sinon
      return b -- return b
    end
end
function max4(a,b,c,d)
    --utilises la fonction precedente pour te faciliter la vie
    max1 = max2(a,b) 
    max2 = max2(c,d)
    --t'as qu'une condition maintenant
    if(max2<max1) then
        return max1
    else
        return max2
    end
end

function max8(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)

    --on utilise max 4 
    max1 = max4(a,b,c,d)
    max2 = max4(e,f,g,h)

    --verifions avec max2 maintenant
    if(max2<max1) then
        return max1
    else
        return max2
    end
end

print("test max8",max8(8,9,7,4,5,28,1,2))
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

I tried to use local, i changed variables. The problem is max8 because when i delete this function and i use max4, it works

Comment: The problem is that you're overwriting the global `max2` function with a number value. You should use local variables and ideally additionally different names.

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, `math.max` works fine with many arguments, so why reimplement it?

Answer (score 3):

Let's review your code function by function.

```lua
function max2(a, b) --fonction (max2)
    if a > b then -- si a est superieur à b alors...
      return a -- return a
    else -- sinon
      return b -- return b
    end
end
```

This function is *fine* semantically. It will be stored in the *global variable* `max2`. Note: Your comments are redundant, I'd remove them. The `else` can also be omitted (you don't have to though). This could be further shortened by using `and` and `or` instead of `if`, but that's not needed.

```lua
function max4(a,b,c,d)
    --utilises la fonction precedente pour te faciliter la vie
    max1 = max2(a,b) 
    max2 = max2(c,d)
    --t'as qu'une condition maintenant
    if(max2<max1) then
        return max1
    else
        return max2
    end
end
```

This is where the problems start. `max2 = max2(c,d)` overwrites your global variable `max2` with a number (hence why you're "getting attempt to call a number value"). *The first call to it will be fine however*, since the right-hand side is evaluated first. *Only on the second call* will you attempt to call the number value. This is why you semi-incorrectly identified `max8` as the source of the problem (**`max8` *does* have the same problem though**).

The proper way to fix this is by making your variables `local`: If you do `local max2 = max2(c, d)`, everything will be fine (although after the assignment, the local variable will "shadow" the function); you don't need to rename. Since such "shadowing" is error prone (e.g. you'd get an error if you reordered the assignments to `local max2 = max2(c,d); local max1 = max2(a,b)`, it is recommended to rename the variables instead.

Note: It is *bad practice* to *only* rename the variables. You should *additionally* make them `local` to prevent surprises such as this one. Here's how that would look like:

```lua
function max4(a,b,c,d)
    local max1 = max2(a,b) 
    local max2 = max2(c,d)
    if(max2<max1) then
        return max1
    else
        return max2
    end
end
```

Finally, note that Lua's builtin `math.max` is variadic, and, in newer versions, even supports the `__lt` metamethod! That is, all your functions are practically redundant with `math.max`; you can pass two, four, or eight parameters and it will work as expected. Here's how you could write a variadic `math.max` yourself:

```lua
return function(
    ... -- any values implementing `<`
)
    local n_args = select("#", ...)
    assert(n_args > 0)
    local max = ...
    for i = 2, n_args do
        local candidate = select(i, ...)
        if max < candidate then
            max = candidate
        end
    end
    return max
end
```

(see https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Lua/blob/main/src/math/max.lua)

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
max2 = max2(c,d)
```

You are actually overwriting the function max2 with the value that it gives. Give your variable a different name. Like for example

```
maxValue2 = max2(c,d)
```

You also have another problem that these variables are all global. You should make them local. Because now you do this for example:

```
max2 = max4(e,f,g,h)
```

But max4 overwrites the global max1 meaning that the line before it was pointless.